# How can I alternate the number of children between odd and even rows?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I searched about it, but with CSS flexbox, there is a problem when I wanna show 3 items for odd rows and 2 items for even rows.

My idea is something like this:
[image]

I tried using some kind of `nth-child` selectors but that was not the complete solution.

Comment: Entirely possible both with CSS-Grid and flexbox. What have you tried, please make an [mcve] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nth-child(5n) would be what you need to start from for a repeating pattern, négative value added can make it start before the first five elements so you can tune it to have the first three in a row.

possible example:

- flex

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 30%;
  /*extra  whatever */
  background: #05709C;
  height: 15vh;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
/* make it start earlier */
div:nth-child(5n - 11),
div:nth-child(5n - 10) {
  min-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

- grid (will require to break it into 6 columns)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

div {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  /*extra  whatever */
  background: #05709C;
  height: 15vh;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}


/* make it start earlier */

div:nth-child(5n - 11),
div:nth-child(5n - 10) {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

another example with grid and nth-child for another repeated pattern : [CSS Grid - repeatable grid-template-areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039979/css-grid-repeatable-grid-template-areas/47040816)

Comment: is there any reason you're using `5n - 11, 5n - 10`? because it works with `5n - 1, 5n` also https://jsfiddle.net/1fgz2oe9/

Comment: @doğukan :) too bad the op didn't find it out tuning it to check out how that worked .

Comment: Hey, @doğukan thanks that worked as well, thanks!

Comment: The formula is this:
```(odd row items count + even row items row )n,
(odd row items count + even row items row )n - 1,
(odd row items count + even row items row )n - 2``` ... and so on.

Comment: Thank you for All of this. I have found it really helpful.