# How can I create a grid layout with dynamically changing column widths?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I want to create a dynamically changing grid layout for an image gallery with same row heights, but different columns widths. I want a pattern to repeat continually, regardless of the number of the items added (the images will come from a JS array and the HTML will be generated from a template literal with variables).

This is the JS:

```
let imgArray = ["img/img-1.jpg", "img/img-2.jpg", "img/img-3.jpg", "img/img-4.jpg", "img/img-5.jpg", "img/img-6.jpg", "img/img-7.jpg"
];

let galleryContainer = document.querySelector(".gallery-container");
 
galleryContainer.innerHTML += `${imgArray.map(img => `
<img src="${img}" alt="gallery-img" />`).join("")}
`;
```

So I want two grid columns with different widths in every row, like this:

40% 60%

60% 40%

40% 60%

etc.

How can I achieve this? It has to be something with grid-auto-columns, nth-child and grid-column. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Add some code that you have tried, so that we can better understand this question

Comment: Firstly you should start with a 10 column grid...then it's a matter of selecting the appropriate `nth-child` and applying the appropriate width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grid`, you will need a template of 3 columns, `40% 20% 40%` and children that span 1 or two columns to be `40%` or `60%` of `width`.

You have a repeated pattern, `:nth-child(n)` is what to use to set the `grid-column` to span every ***N*** children. Your pattern repeats itself every 4 elements so `:nth-child(4n)` is a start.

example

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 20% 40%;
  /* option */ /* gap : 5px ; */
}

section> :nth-child(4n - 2),
section> :nth-child(4n - 1 ) {/* sets for 2,3 6,7, 10,11 ... */
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}


/* demo purpose */

section {
  counter-reset: divs;
}

div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content:'N° ' counter(divs)
}
div:after {content:' 40%';margin:auto;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em;;}
section> :nth-child(4n - 2):after,
section> :nth-child(4n - 1):after {
content:' 60%';
}
div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1em;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

duplicate or similar answers i already shared here

- [How can I alternate the number of children between odd and even rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626009/how-can-i-alternate-the-number-of-children-between-odd-and-even-rows/67626304)
- [CSS Grid - repeatable grid-template-areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039979/css-grid-repeatable-grid-template-areas/47040816)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/xgme/pen/wvegQVW

UI

```
<ul class="mytable">
   <li><div></div><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.mytable {
  width: 500px;
}
.mytable li {
  height: 20px;
  list-style:none;
  width: 100%;
}
.mytable li div {
  height:100%;
  float: left;
}
.mytable li:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(even) {
  width: 60%;
  background: blue;
}
.mytable li:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
}
.mytable li:nth-child(odd) div:nth-child(even) {
  width: 40%;
  background: yellow;
}
.mytable li:nth-child(odd) div:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
}
```